# MemoryError: in creating dendrogram while linkage "ward" in AgglomerativeClustering

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, cluster-analysis, dendrogram

Can't we do AgglomerativeClustering with big datasets? I'm facing issues. I've this dataset.
[image: Dataset]

I tried to create a dendrogram but got the below error. Please suggest any solution:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 wardlink = linkage(data_scaled, method = 'ward')
      2 dend_wardlink = dendrogram(wardlink)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\cluster\hierarchy.py:1060, in linkage(y, method, metric, optimal_ordering)
   1056         if np.all(y >= 0) and np.allclose(y, y.T):
   1057             _warning('The symmetric non-negative hollow observation '
   1058                      'matrix looks suspiciously like an uncondensed '
   1059                      'distance matrix')
-> 1060     y = distance.pdist(y, metric)
   1061 else:
   1062     raise ValueError("`y` must be 1 or 2 dimensional.")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\distance.py:2250, in pdist(X, metric, out, **kwargs)
   2248 if metric_info is not None:
   2249     pdist_fn = metric_info.pdist_func
-> 2250     return pdist_fn(X, out=out, **kwargs)
   2251 elif mstr.startswith("test_"):
   2252     metric_info = _TEST_METRICS.get(mstr, None)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 66.9 GiB for an array with shape (8979943105,) and data type float64
```

Laptop configuration:
Windows 10
RAM - 8 GB

Thanks
Mohit

Comment: Steps in-between are missing. The size of your dataframe that is fed into the dendrogram is too large, check for logical mistakes. Put the error and code as text in the post. @user2779095

Comment: @VishnudevKrishnadas I have put the error and code as text. Skipped to put in between steps because i got an error in this step. All previous steps were to clean and merge the data.